# How to customize product page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, page

How can I customize the product details page in Magento 2?
Where is the .phtml file or layout for that?

Comment: We should read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html

Answer (score 3):

to customise product view page in magento2 you need to create a theme, you can find all information for new theme creation [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

after theme creation, you can manage product page by following path

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

Answer (score 2):

1) you can find the path of the template file by using Debug mode

Login to Admin then follow below options

```
Store->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug->Enable Template Path Hints for storefront->YES
```

after that clear the cache then load product detail page, you can see the template file path of each templates

2) For finding the appropriate layouts please refer official docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html#debug-theme-layout